# ActiveRecord Joins get child objects instead of parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

### My problem:

I have Three models:  Company, Parent, and Child.

Child `belongs_to` Parent which `belongs_to` Company

I need to get all children where a certain attribute is set to false, within one company. (The Parent model has a company_id while the Child model does not.)

### What I'm trying:

I have the following join:

```
@objects = Parent.joins(:childs).where('parents.company_id' => current_user.company_id, 'childs.foo' => false)
```

In my view:

```
<!-- This should be a list of child objects -->
<% @objects.each do |obj| %>
<%= obj.foo %>
<% end %>
```

(foo being the attribute of the child object)

Models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end


class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :company
  ...
end


class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  ...
end
```

However, writing the `Parent.joins(:childs)...` returns an ActiveRecord relation of Parent objects.  (Throwing an error when I try to access the child attributes)  I need the end list to be of child objects.  But I am finding it difficult to do so.

A good answer to this question would be one that:

- Solved this problem in another way that made more sense while not being too computationally intensive.
- Or something that shows how to get a list/relation of child objects instead of the parent objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple, start with the Child class:

```
Child.joins(:parent).where(parents: {company_id: current_user.company_id}, foo: false)
```

I would probably advise using scopes/class methods to accomplish this in a cleaner fashion:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_user(user)
    where(company_id: user.company_id)
  end
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :fooless, ->{where foo: false}
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
Child.joins(:parent).merge(Parent.for_user(current_user)).fooless
```

Comment: That throws the error: `uninitialized constant Child::Parents`

Comment: Can you please post how you have set up your associations?  Do you have a line `belongs_to :parent` in your Child model?

Comment: I have edited my question to show the relevant models.

Comment: @alex0112 - Child should `belong_to :parent` (singular) not `:parents`.  Same for Parent - it `belongs_to :company` (singular) not `:companies`.  Take note that Rails is very particular about using singular and plural form according to its conventions.

Comment: These are not the actual names of the models, they are just examples.  So that would not be affecting the code.   However, for accuracy's sake I will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Perhaps, but the error you provided would occur if singular and plural were not used properly.  It could also happen if you weren't naming an association according to the model and database fields expected - this won't work without a bit of customization when declaring the association.  It would also help if you provided the _actual_ code you are using :)

Comment: This project has several instances where the has_many and belongs_to relationships function as they are supposed to.  Please assume that the plurality/naming of the symbols referring to the models is done correctly.  I am not at liberty to post the actual code of this project.

Comment: @alex0112 - if I were to assume that the association conventions were followed properly, you would not be getting the error you are seeing.  I can confirm that this code works for me as expected.  I suggest doing some analysis on your associations and checking that they all work at a basic level to find the problem.  For example, does calling `Child.first.parent` work for you or does it produce an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64514/discussion-between-alex0112-and-pinnym).

Comment: You were correct.  I had the pluralization wrong in the models. Sorry about the bother!